# clickhouse import csv dictionary

Tags: database, dictionary, clickhouse

New CH user and I'm trying to setup a dictionary that maps airline 2 character codes to airline names to use in the onTime databases I create using the sample data from here https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/getting-started/example-datasets/ontime/

Then I manually created a csv file with these contents:

```
id,code,name
1,UA,United Airlines
2,HA,Hawaiian Airlines
3,OO,SkyWest
4,B6,Jetblue Airway
5,QX,Horizon Air
6,YX,Republic Airway
7,G4,Allegiant Air
8,EV,ExpressJet Airlines
9,YV,Mesa Airlines
10,WN,Southwest Airlines
11,OH,PSA Airlines
12,MQ,Envoy Air
13,9E,Endeavor Air
14,NK,Spirit Airlines
15,AA,American Airlines
16,DL,Delta Air Lines
17,AS,Alaska Airlines
18,F9,Frontier Airlines
```

Created the dictionary

```
CREATE DICTIONARY airlinecompany
(
    id UInt64, 
    code String,
    company String

)
PRIMARY KEY id 
SOURCE(FILE(path '/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/airlinenames.csv' format 'CSV'))
LAYOUT(FLAT())
LIFETIME(3600)
```

I can see the dictionary has been created

```
┌─name───────────┐
│ airlinecompany │
│ ontime         │
└────────────────┘
```

But when I try and list its contents I get this error:

```
Received exception from server (version 22.3.3):
Code: 27. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot parse input: expected ',' before: 'id,code,name\r\n1,UA,United Airlines\r\n2,HA,Hawaiian Airlines\r\n3,OO,SkyWest\r\n4,B6,Jetblue Airway\r\n5,QX,Horizon Air\r\n6,YX,Republic Airway\r\n7,G4,Allegiant Air\r\n8,EV,':
Row 1:
Column 0,   name: id,      type: UInt64, ERROR: text "id,code,na" is not like UInt64

: While executing CSVRowInputFormat. (CANNOT_PARSE_INPUT_ASSERTION_FAILED)
```

But I dont think a csv starts with a , before id. Am I missing something from my creation statement or do I need to generate a csv in a certain way?

*** Edit with correct insert:
2 main things I did wrong before

-Layout needs to be `COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED()`

-Primary key should be`code`

```
CREATE DICTIONARY airlinecompany
(
    id UInt64, 
    code String,
    company String

)
PRIMARY KEY code
SOURCE(FILE(path '/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/airlinenames.csv' format 'CSVWithNames'))
LAYOUT(COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED())
LIFETIME(3600)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV file contains the header so it needs to use [CSVWithNames](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#csvwithnames)-format instead of [CSV](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#csv):

```sql
CREATE DICTIONARY airlinecompany
(
    id UInt64, 
    code String,
    company String

)
PRIMARY KEY id 
SOURCE(FILE(path '/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/airlinenames.csv' format 'CSVWithNames'))
LAYOUT(FLAT())
LIFETIME(3600)
```

Comment: I get a new error now : `Unknown field found in CSVRowInputFormat header: 'name' at position 2 Set the 'input_format_skip_unknown_fields' parameter explicitly to ignore and proceed: While executing CSVRowInputFormat. (INCORRECT_DATA)`

Comment: @chowpay you need either change the column-name in CSV-header from *name* to *company* or change the column-name in *DICTIONARY*-schema from *company* to *name*.

Comment: Yep my dumb mistake that was it. I also added this setting but I dont think that was the problem `SETTINGS(input_format_skip_unknown_fields=1)`